# Moving tick labels closer than "below left" and "below right"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a graph of a parabola and its axis of symmetry. On the `x`-axis, the `x` intercepts are labeled. How do I move the labels closer to the tick marks?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=2.5in, height=2.5in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-7.56,xmax=23.56,
    ymin=-150,ymax=150,
    restrict y to domain=-150:150,
    xtick={-3},
    xticklabel style={font=\tiny, below left},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$3$},
    extra x ticks={19},
    extra x tick style={font=\tiny, xticklabel style={below right}},
    extra x tick labels={19},
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The parabola y = x^{2} - 16x - 57 is drawn over the interval [8-11*sqrt(2), 8+11*sqrt(2)].
%Its x-intercepts are (-3,0) and (19,0), and its vertex is (8,-121).
\addplot[domain={8-11*sqrt(2)}:{8+11*sqrt(2)}] {x^2 - 16*x - 57};

%The axis of symmetry is drawn.
\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, domain=-140:140] (8,x) node[pos=0.2, anchor=south, font=\scriptsize, sloped]{$x=8$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add `draw` to the `xticklabel style`, you'll see that there is some padding between the node text and the border, this is the `inner sep` (default 0.333em):

[image]

Reducing the `inner sep`, by adding `inner sep=0pt` (or some other value) to the style in question will do what you ask. Here is with zero inner sep:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=2.5in, height=2.5in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-7.56,xmax=23.56,
    ymin=-150,ymax=150,
    restrict y to domain=-150:150,
    xtick={-3},
    xticklabel style={font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt, below left},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$3$},
    extra x ticks={19},
    extra x tick style={font=\tiny, xticklabel style={below right}},
    extra x tick labels={19},
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The parabola y = x^{2} - 16x - 57 is drawn over the interval [8-11*sqrt(2), 8+11*sqrt(2)].
%Its x-intercepts are (-3,0) and (19,0), and its vertex is (8,-121).
\addplot[domain={8-11*sqrt(2)}:{8+11*sqrt(2)}] {x^2 - 16*x - 57};

%The axis of symmetry is drawn.
\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, domain=-140:140] (8,x) node[pos=0.2, anchor=south, font=\scriptsize, sloped]{$x=8$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As marmot suggests, does `below right=0em` render the same distance as specifying `inner sep=0pt`?

Comment: @user74973 No, `below right` is the same as `anchor=north west`, the offset is zero by default. `inner sep=0` doesn't move the anchor point of the node, `below right=<offset>` does move the anchor point.

Comment: Do you have to specify `inner sep=0pt` in `extra x tick style`?

Comment: Would `below right=-0.333em` render the same distance as specifying `inner sep=0pt`?

Comment: @user74973 Don't know, not sure how it's measured.

Comment: @Adelyn As you can see if you test, no. I think the extra x ticks initially use the same style as the normal ticks, so when you have `xticklabel style={inner sep=0pt,...}` that applies to the extra ticks as well.

Comment: @user74973 Just tested, seems the answer is yes: `\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.2pt]; \node [draw,ultra thin,red,below right=-0.333em] {foo}; \node [draw,ultra thin,opacity=0.5,blue,below right,inner sep=0pt] {foo}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to move the labels around (in case they interfere with some other elements) is to add some distance after `below left` or `below right`. **EDIT** This option is deprecated, unless used together with the `positioning` library. (A big thanks to  Torbjørn T. !)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=2.5in, height=2.5in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-7.56,xmax=23.56,
    ymin=-150,ymax=150,
    restrict y to domain=-150:150,
    xtick={-3},
    xticklabel style={font=\tiny, below left=-0.4em},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$3$},
    extra x ticks={19},
    extra x tick style={font=\tiny, xticklabel style={below right=-0.4em}},
    extra x tick labels={19},
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The parabola y = x^{2} - 16x - 57 is drawn over the interval [8-11*sqrt(2), 8+11*sqrt(2)].
%Its x-intercepts are (-3,0) and (19,0), and its vertex is (8,-121).
\addplot[domain={8-11*sqrt(2)}:{8+11*sqrt(2)}] {x^2 - 16*x - 57};

%The axis of symmetry is drawn.
\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, domain=-140:140] (8,x) node[pos=0.2, anchor=south, font=\scriptsize, sloped]{$x=8$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Just noticed that the manual considers using `below right=<offset>` as deprecated *unless* the `positioning` library is loaded (see description of the `above right` key on page 228).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! Didn't know that!

Comment: @TorbjørnT., my understanding is different:  "Does the same as anchor=south east. Note that giving both above and left options does not have
the same effect as above left, rather only the last left “wins.” Actually, this option also takes an
hoffseti parameter, but using this parameter without using the positioning library is deprecated. (The
positioning library changes the meaning of this parameter to something more sensible.)". i understand this, that use use `above right` -- if you not load `positioning` library --deprecated. otherwise its use (when library is loaded)  is ok.

Comment: @Zarko We agree then, that's exactly what I wrote.